# Bash runs executable fine in 10.04 but not in 11.10 or 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bash, virtualbox

First post, but I come here often and this is the first time I haven't found the answer already posted, so I registered.

I have a simple binary executable that runs fine in 10.04.

```
./buds
Opening serial device '/dev/ttyS0' (19200,8N1)...OK
Creating PTY device...OK
Setting PTY device '/dev/pts/1' (115200,8N1)...OK
Startup complete, waiting for commands...
```

But does not in 11.10 Live CD or 12.04 under VirtualBox:

```
cd Test
ls
buds
./buds
bash: ./buds: No such file or directory
```

I've made sure that buds is executable and that I have permissions:

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l buds
```

-rwxr-xr-x 1 chris chris 26240 Jun 22  2010 buds

```
file buds 
buds: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xf8f0b93813114695c72203bdc1bcf47163553eab, stripped 

ldd buds
not a dynamic executable
```

Yikes!

Comment: Please add the output of `file buds` and `ldd buds`

Comment: chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ file buds
buds: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xf8f0b93813114695c72203bdc1bcf47163553eab, stripped
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ ldd buds
 not a dynamic executable

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that your binary was built for 32-bit systems. Try installing the 32-bit C library:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

If it still does not want to run, use `ldd` to find out the library names. If `libx11.so` is missing, you probably need a package named like `libx11`. You can always use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find out the package name by searching for file name.

Comment: Right on Lekensteyn.  I found this out for myself a few minutes ago and tried the chrooot method with no luck.  Your answer worked, the file runs, but now I have "permission denied" when trying to open /dev/ttyS0.

Comment: Ok, a simple "sudo ./buds" worked wonders!  Thanks Lekensteyn.

Comment: Changing the file permissions and/ or groupship of `/dev/ttyS0` is preferred over running the program as root (unless it really need to do administrative tasks).